# Improve t-sql views

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a query that basically pulls multiple columns from multiple views. Is it better to index each views for faster performance?

query i.e. A to G are views

```
SELECT A.C1, B.C1
FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.C3=B.C3 
Inner join C on C.C2 = B.C2
inner join D on D.C4 = C.C4
...
Inner join H ON H.C5 = G.C5
where <some condition>
```

Each views (A to H) are pulling data from different tables. None of the views are indexed (I don't see anything when I expand the INDEX folder within the view's tree). Should I add index in each of these views for faster performance? If so, should I add index on the columns I am using for ON JOIN clause?

Thank you

Comment: You typically start indexing on the parent tables before moving to the view.

Comment: If performance is a concern, querying multiple views is a significant handicap.

Comment: Tables have indexes on them. Performance is slow...should I query the tables? I will have to use the same code as views though to get the same output...

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your tables and the indexes.

Comment: There are many tables and a lot of those tables have multiple indexes on them (unique - Non-Clustered, Non-Unique-Non-Clustered, Clustered etc)..

Comment: How often are the tables updated?  Maintaining the indexes on the views can generate a lot of overhead.

Comment: One advice. Never use 'view join view' unless that is the only option you have. Try to use the underlying tables in your query instead of views. Then you see what indexes might be needed on the tables. But dont just add the index because your query need it. You have to analyze the overhead of the indexes and the benefits of indexes you are getting and then based on that add any index.

Comment: Also, unless you are running SQL Developer or Enterprise, SQL Server won't automatically use indexes on your views anyway.  For SQL Standard edition to use an index on a view you need to add a hint called NOEXPAND to each view reference in your query.

Comment: Don't just assume that you'd be able to index the views anyway. There are a number of restrictions that you have to meet in order to be able to index a view. The chances of the existing views meeting those restrictions by chance is low, in my experience.

Comment: I have chosen to join tables instead of views. I looked at execution plan (didn't fine scan...found seek which is better...right?) Thanks for some useful information for future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enable the "Include Actual Execution Plan" and run your query to see where the performance hit is. Look for "Table scan" as a possible culprit.

If nothing obvious is found, try Query -> "Analyze query in database engine tuning advisor". SQL server will suggest some indexes to add. Don't just apply them all but compare against the existing queries to make sure you aren't adding too much overlap.

As nkj said, optimze queries on tables before indexing the views.

Comment: I looked at the execution plan and looks like no table scan...mostly seek. I am not going to add indexes on views for heavy maintenance reasons. :)